# Unable to serve shopify node app using cli

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I created a shopify node app using the shopify-cli and ran it using `shopify node serve`, but the app does not load, it keeps on loading forever and then gives out the following error in the console:

[click to open the image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WvGi.png)

I'm using Windows 10 with cmd for the shell to run shopify-cli

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you try with another one?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu I'm using chrome for development but I've tried using both firefox and edge chromium, it just doesn't work, both browsers show errors and the same thing  happens, the app keeps on loading forever and there's nothing on the  browser window. There's just this error in the browser's console.

Comment: Did you check this question on Shopify forum https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/from-today-i-am-not-able-to-run-my-shopify-store/m-p/1128330#M65061 ?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu This fixed the issue for me, thank you so much! You're a real life saver!